# How can I test live data object in Android MVVM

Tags: android, unit-testing, kotlin, mvvm, android-viewmodel

Hi I am trying to test livedata which is in my viewmodel, I have written to test to verify that the repository call has been made

how can I check if the live data object in this case, and what additional test cases I should be writing for this code in viewModel

Thanks
R

MainActivityViewModel

```
class MainActivityViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val dataRepository: DataRepository
): ViewModel() {
    val _charactersLiveData = MutableLiveData<Result<ArrayList<Character>>>()
    val charactersLiveData: LiveData<Result<ArrayList<Character>>> = _charactersLiveData

    fun fetchCharacters() {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            _charactersLiveData.value = dataRepository.getCharacters()
        }
    }
}
```

MainActivityViewModelTest

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner::class)
class MainActivityViewModelTest {

    @get:Rule
    val coroutineRule = MainCoroutineRule()

    @Mock
    private lateinit var dataRepository: DataRepository

    @InjectMocks
    private lateinit var mainActivityViewModel: MainActivityViewModel

    @Test
    fun fetchCharacters() {
        runBlockingTest {
            mainActivityViewModel.fetchCharacters()
            verify(dataRepository).getCharacters()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If LiveData references the Repository, then I would verify the function in the mock is called, which you've already done. One thing to note is ViewModel should inject the Dispatcher into the constructor so you can use the Main.Dispatcher in the test so results return syncqentailly.

Comment: Could you share an example of this please

Comment: This free course has an extensive section dedicated to testing. It shows how to test `LiveData` as well:  https://www.udacity.com/course/advanced-android-with-kotlin--ud940

Answer (score 2):

You can reference this article: https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/unit-testing-livedata-and-other-common-observability-problems-bb477262eb04

The main idea here is:

- Mock `dataRepository`
- When `dataRepository` calls `getCharacters()`, it should return the testing value. E.g. `listOf('a')`
- Execute `mainActivityViewModel.fetchCharacters()`
- Expect the value of your live data

```
assertEquals(mainActivityViewModel.charactersLiveData.getOrAwaitValue(), listOf('a'))
```

Comment: Although LiveData is dead, but reference article shows that they knew test side of API was broken, they just went with a follow up blog.

Answer (score 1):

Try this if any issues then let me know. I have try to do according to your class and data but if you need then can changes.

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner::class)
class MainActivityViewModelTest {

@get:Rule
val coroutineRule = MainCoroutineRule()

@Mock
private lateinit var dataRepository: DataRepository

@InjectMocks
private lateinit var mainActivityViewModel: MainActivityViewModel

@Mock
private lateinit var dataObserver:  Observer<Result<List<Character>>>

@Test
fun fetchCharacters() {
    runBlockingTest {
        Mockito.`when`(datarepository).getcharacter()
        .thenreturn(Result.success(listOf(Character (
        Name=A,
        Type=hero))))
mainActivityViewModel.fetchCharacters()
mainActivityViewModel.charactersLiveData.observeForever(dataObserver)
Mockito.verify(dataRepository).getCharacters()
Mockito.verify(dataObserver).onChanged(Result.success(listOf(Character (
  Name=A,
  Type=hero))))
mainActivityViewModel.charactersLiveData.removeObserver(dataObserver)
            }
        }

}
```